# mollom wordpress plugin captcha is not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i installed mollom wordpress for my wp web site and active the plugin like they said..,other function are working but captch function is not working

this is the link to the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mollom/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this plugins for captcha in my site Please check it and it works fine.
If you want to change captcha plugins please check this [Plugins link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/si-captcha-for-wordpress/screenshots/)

Answer (score 2):

As the author of the plugin. I want to give some context about the state of the Mollom plugin: The stable version (v. 0.7.5) hasn't been updated in a very long time. However, WordPress backward compatibility still allows this plugin to function. I've been using it on my own blog until very recently.

However, things have moved forward on the Mollom service. Most importantly: there's a completely 'new' [REST based API](http://mollom.com/api) and numerous improvements.

Currently, work on a completely revamped version of the plugin is under way. Development + documentation for this new version can be tracked on github:

https://github.com/Mollom/wordpress-mollom

We're happy to welcome any kind of feedback. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Mollom plugin for WordPress has been completely rewritten and redone recently -- including a new home:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/mollom/

The new plugin and release was announced just today on http://daniel.kudwien.net/2013/07/stop-blog-spam-on-wordpress/

As the [FAQ](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mollom/faq/) clarifies, your theme needs to use WordPress core API function to print the comment form:

```
<?php comment_form(); ?>
```

This will invoke the required hook callbacks, which the Mollom plugin is using to add the CAPTCHA and other elements to the comment form.  The function was introduced in WordPress 3.0.

You can find examples for how and where to use the `comment_form()` function by looking at the default themes that ship with WordPress; e.g., the *Twenty Twelve* theme (but also all earlier).